# "replace is not a function"

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm trying to remove the comma from a number.

```
var thisbill_str = ""; 
thisbill = $('#linebill_' + z).val(); 
if (isNaN(thisbill) ) { thisbill = 0.00; } 
thisbill_str = thisbill; 
thisbill = thisbill_str.replace(/,/g, "");
```

This javascript code is giving me an error:

```
TypeError: thisbill_str.replace is not a function
```

It doesn't matter if I give it the 'g' and 'i' flags.
It only does it if the string does NOT already have a comma in it, i.e., if the string is '515.00'. If the string were '5,515.00', then it works fine.
I don't see anything in the documentation that tells me that the string to be replaced has to actually exist. What am I missing, and what is a better way to do this?

Comment: Please show us exactly what `thisbill_str` has in it when it doesn't work.  Even better to make a jsFiddle that shows the problem.  Probably `thisbill_str` isn't a string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is most likely caused by thisbill_str being something other than a String.  Maybe you have some other code somewhere that automatically converts thisbill_str to a Number?

You can convert back to a string using [String(thisbill_str)](http://www.javascripture.com/String#String).

The complete code would be:

```js
thisbill = String(thisbill_str).replace(",", "")
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you. I just had to cast it to a string. I forget that javascript is not really strongly typed.

Answer (score 2):

```
thisbill_str = thisbill;
```

You should be casting to a string here. `thisbill_str` is still a number, so it doesn't have a replace method.

```
thisbill_str = thisbill + '';
```

Answer (score 1):

`TypeError: thisbill_str.replace is not a function`

`thisbill_str` can't be coerced in to a String object, therefore it doesn't have the `replace` method.

Is the value of `thisbill_str` null?

Comment: If it was `null/undefined` it would be a different error as those values *cannot* have properties ;-) I'm going to guess a DOM element, but same idea: `thisbill_str` does not evaluate to a String.

Comment: No, I initialized it to "", then later I put a float into it. Let's say the float was 515.00.

Comment: @user2539612 So then it evaluates to a *number* (which is not a *string* and thus doesn't have a `replace` method). Remember that variables/properties in JavaScript do not have types - the values that result from their evaluation have types.

Comment: @user2539612 can you show a cut-down version of your code that still exhibits the error?

Comment: @user2246674 Any `Number` object coerces to a `String` object just fine.

Comment: @David-SkyMesh Not when a receiver: `(515.00).replace()` will result in the same error (your answer is ultimately correct - it is *not* a string).

Comment: Sure, and I appreciate the help. Here is the cut-down version: var thisbill_str = "";
            thisbill = $('#linebill_' + z).val();  
            if (isNaN(thisbill) ) {
                thisbill = 0.00;
            }
            thisbill_str = thisbill;
            thisbill = thisbill_str.replace(/,/g, "");

Comment: @user2539612 "So then it [`thisbill_str`] evaluates to a *number* (which is not a string and thus doesn't have a replace method) .."

Comment: My apologies. I haven't posted on here enough to know how to format code. I should have read the directions. Is it legible?